# How do I get an older asp.net project to load in VS2017?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a few older asp.net projects. These mostly don't seem to open in VS2017. Instead they generate the following error in the output window:

> C:\my\project\path.csproj : error  : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

This seems to affect most web projects: asp.net forms and Web API alike. It doesn't seem to affect any other project types. However, I do have at least one project that does load up in VS2017 just fine. I'm not seeing much difference between loading and non-loading projects.

Is there a way to make these projects load successfully in both VS2015 and VS2017? If so what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused, at least in my case, by the MSBuildExtensionsPath32 setting. This is a setting to change the path of some of the files used by msbuild - it is especially common to see it used for web projects.

Not loading in VS2017:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildExtensionsPath32>.\webMsbuild\</MSBuildExtensionsPath32>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Loading successfully:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```